# Testing EF Core with relational data, schema and transactions

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I have a problem creating a unit test with EF Core (2.0.1).

I create my db with the following options:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    .ConfigureWarnings((b) =>
    {
        b.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning);
    })
    .Options;
```

The code I want to test looks something like this:

```
using (IDbContextTransaction transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
{
    await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("DELETE FROM fooSchema.Customers WHERE ID = {0}", id);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Other stuff...

    context.Customers.Add(fooCustomer);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

First I had the issue with InMemory not supporting transactions. I solved it using `ConfigureWarnings` as shown in the code. But then it turns out InMemory doesn't handle `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`. So then I tried SQLLite, but it doesn't handle custom schemas instead.

**How do I create a DbContext, without any "real" DB, that handles transactions, schema and ExecuteSqlCommandAsync?**

It is OK to suppress the error from `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`. But I cannot find the `EventId` for it. In reality it works great, this is just for the unit test.

Comment: Why are you using ExecuteSqlCommandAsync?

Comment: @Tubs in my case I find it more efficient when deleting several items without knowing the id's. This particular table has a clustered key. I cannot read all the items I want to delete into memory.

Comment: Did you find anything on this? I'm starting to think the approach is to mock out EF Core in its entirety for testing, however difficult/bad that might be.

Comment: @RanSagy no. I did not solve it.